# How to Show Edit button in Navigation bar

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib

I'm using this line of code

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem=self.editButtonItem;
```

But there is no edit button appearing in the navigation bar.
using xib files and not storyboard. Any help in solving the problem to let the button appears ?

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10100038/how-to-add-bar-button-in-navigation-bar-without-navigation-controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this code:

```
UIBarButtonItem *editBtn = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"edit.png"] style:UIBarButtonSystemItemEdit target:self action:@selector(myAction:)];

self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = revealButton;
```

You can customize it by setting left or right.

And on myAction: you can put your action method.

Hope it help.

Comment: I want to use this edit button to delete records from the table view

Answer (score -1):

```
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
```

May be it can help u